# What is the return value of update_all() in ActiveRecord / Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

The Ruby on Rails and ActiveRecord documentation, Google, and StackOverflow are conspiratorially silent on the return value of update_all()

What does update_all() return?

- Number of records?
- Success status?
- ID's of updated records?

Comment: Checked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5023332/how-to-verify-if-update-all-was-actually-updated-in-rails)?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

ActiveRecord's update_all() returns the number of records updated.

```
describe '.update_all' do
  let!(:user1) { create :user, last_name: 'Smitty' }
  let!(:user2) { create :user, last_name: 'Smitty' }
  let!(:user3) { create :user, last_name: 'Doe' }

  it 'returns number of records updated' do
    expect(User.where(last_name: 'Smitty')
               .update_all(last_name: 'Smith')).to eq 2
  end
end
```

Yields:

```
User
  .update_all
    returns number of records updated

Finished in 0.1245 seconds (files took 13.17 seconds to load)
1 example, 0 failures
```

Comment: Maybe also post a PR with the documentation fix? This info, indeed, looks like something that should be there.

Comment: I rise to the occasion, @SergioTulentsev! I thought it would be a quick clone/edit/push/PR...but I've never contributed to rails before. Working through getting rails-dev-box set up now...

Answer (score 3):

The documentation has been updated:

> Returns the number of rows affected.

https://api.rubyonrails.org/v6.1.4/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-update_all